# Lock multiple mysql table for a java function

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, locking

In the function there are multiple getAll(), saveOrUpdate() called for many classes (tables)

I want add locks for this tables using Hibernate so that any other application can't access the tables that I'm working with.

Is there a way to add locks for tables until the function complete the execution.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {HibernateException.class, Exception.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Override
public void import(){
...
}
```

Comment: You can use `select ... for update` logic or set transaction isolation level to SERIALIZED (if you DB allows this)

Comment: I'm relativily new to locking mechanisms are you saying that if I added a ',isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE' it will lock the table. but I haven't mention any tables for the transaction early on. So how can they lock the tables

Comment: Tables are used in your Entities. Your code uses entities and the tables are locked. From explanations `A serializable execution is defined to be an execution of the operations of concurrently executing SQL-transactions that produces the same effect as some serial execution of those same SQL-transactions. A serial execution is one in which each SQL-transaction executes to completion before the next SQL-transaction begins.`

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL for the explanation and for the help